# Why div animation keyframe is not working when javascript engine is busy?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations, loader

I have page structure as bellow:

```
<head>

 <style>
    .windows8 {
      position: relative;
      width: 78px;
      height:78px;
      margin:auto;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }

    .windows8 .wBall {
      position: absolute;
      width: 74px;
      height: 74px;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(225deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
      animation: orbit 6.96s infinite;
      -o-animation: orbit 6.96s infinite;
      -ms-animation: orbit 6.96s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: orbit 6.96s infinite;
      -moz-animation: orbit 6.96s infinite;
    }

    .windows8 .wBall .wInnerBall{
      position: absolute;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      background: rgb(93, 147, 195);
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .windows8 #1wBall_1,.windows8 #wBall_1 {
      animation-delay: 1.52s;
      -o-animation-delay: 1.52s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 1.52s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1.52s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 1.52s;
    }

    .windows8 #1wBall_2,.windows8 #wBall_2 {
      animation-delay: 0.3s;
      -o-animation-delay: 0.3s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 0.3s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    }

    .windows8 #1wBall_3,.windows8 #wBall_3 {
      animation-delay: 0.61s;
      -o-animation-delay: 0.61s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 0.61s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.61s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.61s;
    }

    .windows8 #1wBall_4,.windows8 #wBall_4 {
      animation-delay: 0.91s;
      -o-animation-delay: 0.91s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 0.91s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.91s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.91s;
    }

    .windows8 #1wBall_5,.windows8 #wBall_5 {
      animation-delay: 1.22s;
      -o-animation-delay: 1.22s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 1.22s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1.22s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 1.22s;
    }



    @keyframes orbit {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      }

      7% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(300deg);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        origin:0%;
      }

      30% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform:rotate(410deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        origin:7%;
      }

      39% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(645deg);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        origin:30%;
      }

      70% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(770deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        origin:39%;
      }

      75% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(900deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        origin:70%;
      }

      76% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform:rotate(900deg);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotate(900deg);
      }
    }

    @-o-keyframes orbit {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      }

      7% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
        -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -o-origin:0%;
      }

      30% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform:rotate(410deg);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -o-origin:7%;
      }

      39% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: rotate(645deg);
        -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -o-origin:30%;
      }

      70% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: rotate(770deg);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -o-origin:39%;
      }

      75% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: rotate(900deg);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -o-origin:70%;
      }

      76% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform:rotate(900deg);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: rotate(900deg);
      }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes orbit {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      }

      7% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -ms-origin:0%;
      }

      30% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform:rotate(410deg);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -ms-origin:7%;
      }

      39% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: rotate(645deg);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -ms-origin:30%;
      }

      70% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: rotate(770deg);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -ms-origin:39%;
      }

      75% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: rotate(900deg);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -ms-origin:70%;
      }

      76% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform:rotate(900deg);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: rotate(900deg);
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes orbit {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      }

      7% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-origin:0%;
      }

      30% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(410deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -webkit-origin:7%;
      }

      39% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(645deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-origin:30%;
      }

      70% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(770deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -webkit-origin:39%;
      }

      75% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(900deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -webkit-origin:70%;
      }

      76% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(900deg);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(900deg);
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes orbit {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      }

      7% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -moz-origin:0%;
      }

      30% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform:rotate(410deg);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -moz-origin:7%;
      }

      39% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(645deg);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -moz-origin:30%;
      }

      70% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(770deg);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -moz-origin:39%;
      }

      75% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotate(900deg);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -moz-origin:70%;
      }

      76% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform:rotate(900deg);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(900deg);
      }
    }
  </style>

<!-- 4-5 style links-->

<!-- 4-5 scripts -->

<!-- for testing you can put following code
  for(var i=0;i<-1;i++){console.log(i)}
-->
</head>

<body>
  <app>

    <div class="windows8">
      <div class="wBall" id="wBall_1">
        <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wBall" id="wBall_2">
        <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wBall" id="wBall_3">
        <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wBall" id="wBall_4">
        <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wBall" id="wBall_5">
        <div class="wInnerBall"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app>

</body>
```

It renders the divs with all its css(e.g ball radius and background-color etc.) but key-frame(i.e. transition/movement) of ball are not working upto some time (until all css/js is downloded and parsed) but after that it works fine.

> I thought may be while loading and parsing css/js the rendering engine will be busy so it can't execute transition but when I took a look on other web-pages they uses css loaders as I do and it is working fine. So how their animation is working when mine not.

Answer (score 1):

Because browser tabs are single threaded. Some browsers are single threaded, entirely.

If the JavaScript never stops running in some browsers you can’t even close the tab.

If you want the DOM to repaint, or canvas to animate, or the page to be clickable, you can *not* lock JS up. Which means that you have to learn different programming paradigms to break up long-running processes.